# Optimization of a MySQL query in php

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

How can I optimize below query

```sql
CREATE TABLE $fullTableName AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `impCnt`,
IF(COUNT(*)>7,7,COUNT(*)) AS `impGroup`,
MIN(ad.`created`) AS `dateFirstImp`,
ad.sid,
IF(cl.`clicks` IS NULL, 0, cl.`clicks`) AS `clickCnt`,
st.`panelistID` AS panelistID,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(lbs.`site`, '') ORDER BY lbs.`table-order`,lbs.`value-order` ASC SEPARATOR '~'),'~',1) as 'site',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(lbs.`dimension`, '') ORDER BY lbs.`table-order`,lbs.`value-order` ASC SEPARATOR '~'),'~',1) as 'dimension'
FROM table1 ad
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.`parameter` as 'parameter', v.`value` as 'value',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('site',t.attributes),v.`site`,null) as 'site',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('placement',t.attributes),v.`placement`,null) as 'placement',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('format',t.attributes),v.`format`,null) as 'format',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('creative',t.attributes),v.`creative`,null) as 'creative',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('mediaOwner',t.attributes),v.`mediaOwner`,null) as 'mediaOwner',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('targeting',t.attributes),v.`targeting`,null) as 'targeting',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('dimension',t.attributes),v.`dimension`,null) as 'dimension',
    t.`order` as 'table-order', v.`order` as 'value-order' FROM table2 t
    JOIN table3 v ON (t.tableID=v.tableID) WHERE t.campaignID = 1856
    AND t.`active`=1 AND t.`ignore`=0 ORDER BY t.`order`,v.`order`
) lbs ON ($string)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cl2.`memberid` as memberid,
    cl2.`panelid` as panelid,COUNT(*) as clicks
    FROM table4 cl2 WHERE 1 AND (1) GROUP BY cl2.`memberid`,cl2.`panelid`
) cl
ON (ad.`memberid`=cl.`memberid` AND ad.`panelid`=cl.`panelid`)
LEFT JOIN table5 st
ON (ad.`memberid`=st.`panelistID` AND ad.`panelid`=st.`panelID`)
JOIN table6 ef
ON (ef.`panelID`=st.`panelID` AND ef.`panelistID`=st.`panelistID`)
WHERE 1 AND (1) GROUP BY ad.`memberid`, ad.`panelid` ORDER BY ad.`memberid` ASC, ad.`panelid` ASC)
```

Comment: Have you checked similar questions that deal with query optimization? If not, please check them out and pay attention to what information is provided along the query. If you don't do so, then no one can help you optimize your query (we don't have your data and we don't have the same MySQL settings / server hardware so we can't run the query).

Comment: Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is especially inefficient; can you avoid multiple subqueries like that?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a variety of questions come to mind... First, a little cleanup of the query for readability purposes...

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS impCnt,
      IF( COUNT(*) > 7, 7 , COUNT(*) ) AS impGroup,
      MIN(ad.created) AS dateFirstImp,
      ad.sid,
      IF(cl.clicks IS NULL, 0, cl.clicks ) AS clickCnt,
      st.panelistID,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(lbs.site, '') ORDER BY lbs.`table-order`, lbs.`value-order` ASC SEPARATOR '~'),'~',1) as 'site',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(lbs.dimension, '') ORDER BY lbs.`table-order`,lbs.`value-order` ASC SEPARATOR '~'),'~',1) as 'dimension'
   FROM 
      table1 ad
         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           t.`parameter` as 'parameter', 
                           v.`value` as 'value',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('site',t.attributes),v.site,null) as 'site',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('placement',t.attributes),v.placement,null) as 'placement',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('format',t.attributes),v.format,null) as 'format',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('creative',t.attributes),v.creative,null) as 'creative',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('mediaOwner',t.attributes),v.mediaOwner,null) as 'mediaOwner',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('targeting',t.attributes),v.targeting,null) as 'targeting',
                           IF(FIND_IN_SET('dimension',t.attributes),v.dimension,null) as 'dimension',
                           t.`order` as 'table-order', 
                           v.`order` as 'value-order' 
                        FROM 
                           table2 t
                              JOIN table3 v 
                                 ON t.tableID = v.tableID
                        WHERE 
                               t.campaignID = 1856
                           AND t.active = 1 
                           AND t.ignore = 0 
                        ORDER BY 
                           t.`order`,
                           v.`order` ) lbs 
            ON ($string)

         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           cl2.memberid as memberid,
                           cl2.panelid as panelid,
                           COUNT(*) as clicks
                        FROM 
                           table4 cl2 
                        WHERE 
                           1 AND (1) 
                        GROUP BY 
                           cl2.memberid,
                           cl2.panelid ) cl
            ON ad.memberid = cl.memberid
            AND ad.panelid = cl.panelid

         LEFT JOIN table5 st
            ON ad.memberid = st.panelistID
            AND ad.panelid = st.panelID

         JOIN table6 ef
            ON ef.panelID = st.panelID
            AND ef.panelistID = st.panelistID 

   WHERE 
      1 AND (1) 
   GROUP BY 
      ad.memberid, 
      ad.panelid
   ORDER BY 
      ad.memberid ASC, 
      ad.panelid ASC
```

You obviously are trying to make generic via your table names, but using aliases is fine to show the relationships.

1. Your join to the subquery alias "lbs" based on ($string), but don't give any context / sample of what that might be -- filtered and/or actual join criteria?
2. Your inner select that is the basis of "lbs" alias is only using the "site" and "dimension" columns in your final outer query... why do FIND_IN_SET for all the other columns.
3. Based on "lbs" query, your table2 (t alias) should have a compound index on ( campaignID, active, ignore, order ) to help optimize that part of the query AND the order by clause.
4. Your final group by / order by against your (ad alias) table should have a compound index on ( memberid, panelid ) at a minimum with additional columns IN FRONT of these based on the "criteria" you are looking for from your "ad" table.
5. Your (cl2 alias) should have a compound index on ( memberid, panelid ) PLUS additional columns in FRONT of these based on your "WHERE 1 AND (1) " criteria which is ambiguous and just place-holders for actual filtering criteria.  Without sample true context of that, we can't offer better index column optimizations to you.
6. Your final WHERE clauses of "1 AND (1)"... same ambiguity as #5.